# How to generate coverage.ec file using Emma

Tags: java, emma

I am trying to execute emma commands by accessing the emma api. The code is as follows:

```
String commandName = "instr";
commandArgs = {"-cp", "target/classes", "-d","target/instr-class"};
final Command command = Command.create(commandName, "emma ".concat (commandName),commandArgs);
command.run();
```

If I write code like this it's internally the same as:

```
java emma instr -d outinstr -ip out
```

If I give **report** as commandName instead of **instr** it executes like

```
java emma report -r txt,html -in coverage.em -in coverage.ec
```

taking instr and report like commands.

But when there are no commands like instr, report, how do I execute

```
java -cp 1outinstr;out Main
```

like the earlier code ?

Answer (score 0):

After testing any time you can take `.ec` file while your server is running. Emma store the `.ec` file value in JVM and we can request it by command

```
java -cp emma.jar emma ctl -connect serverIp:47653 -command coverage.get,$pathToStoreECFile
```

After that u can generate report of testing by command

```
java emma report -r txt,html -in coverage.em,coverage.ec
```

**NOTE:** only one in require for all input file you can separate file with "," (**Without Space**) and you can change port number from default properties file of Emma.